# Rails: Credit Card Validator gem - need good example of how to use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credit-card

I am looking to use the credit card validator gem to validate credit card numbers and types.  I'm still relatively new to rails and even though I've taken a look at the github documentation I am still trying to work out how to best use this gem.  Would I need to put some code into the model? If so, how exactly? Do I need to use a validate_with?

I've done a few google searches but can't seem to find any examples of how best to use this gem and where to put the code.

Seems that my reputation is getting shot on here :(

Here is what I did.  In my creditcard model I added the following line:

```
validates_with ValidateCreditCard
```

I then created the file lib/validate_credit_card.rb as follows:

```
class ValidateCreditCard < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if !CreditCardValidator::Validator.valid?(record.card_number.to_s)
      record.errors[:base] << "The credit card number is not valid."
    end
  end
end
```

I also had to put the following line into my config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths      += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

This seems to be working, however, if this the best way of doing this?

Also, even though I can see the error message when I enter an invalid credit card number, the credit card field doesn't get surrounded in red, so I need to look into the whole errors[:base] and how that works.

Would appreciate some feedback in regards to this being the right way of doing this type of validation.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a programming forum. When you ask a question, you are typically expected to include what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked, preferably with code snippets and error logs. That way, people can judge your level of understanding and the context in which you are asking the question.

Comment: Fair enough..I can do that. I was mainly looking for direction though on the best way to actually use this gem.  I've tried numerous Google searches and just can't find any real examples.  I'll perform some code and update after that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work.

I added the following lines to my creditcard model:

```
validate :validate_credit_card

private

def validate_credit_card
  if !CreditCardValidator::Validator.valid?(:card_number.to_s)
    errors.add(:card_number, "is not valid.")
  end
end
```

Comment: The above didn't actually work for some reason. Not sure why.  I went back to what I put in my original post and that does work.